# one way bearing in solidworks

Tags: gears, solidworks, bearings

I'm relatively new to solidworks and i would like to know if there is a way to mate a bearing in solidworks such that it acts as a one way bearing. In the rack and pinion setup in the figure, the rack is the driver and reciprocates, i want the shaft to turn only clockwise and freewheel in the other direction.

I havent been able to find any way to perform this mate and motion study dosent help either. Ive also searched for cad files on it but its also a dead end.[image]

I use SW2016

Comment: AFAIK there is no simple to achieve this in solidworks. You might be able to do this if you deconstruct your bearing and add ratchet and pawl features, or whatever locking mechanisms are present, and add distance/rotation limit mates.

Comment: Thats the problem. If i could create a cad file for the bearing (which i dont), further analysis won't be as accurate as if i had gotten the bearing cad file from the manufacturer i plan on using. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the CAD model to be terribly accurate internally. The envelope dimensions are probably accurate but manufacturers are hesitant to release detailed models depicting roller geometry, raceway profile, locking mechanism, etc. Depending on what your analysis is I wouldn't trust that model to be overly accurate.

Comment: A bearing that would do that is based on a ramp and roller mechanism - a oneway clutch often used in starter motors.

Comment: I think the best workaround for this is to have two alternate configurations - one with the concentric mate between bearing and shaft having it's rotation locked, and one without. You would need to switch between the two configurations according to which direction the rack is moving in.

Comment: @Solar Mike- do you know where i can find cad files on the mechanism?

Comment: @ Jonathan- i understand what you mean but im not sure how to implement it. How can i switch between the 2 configurations when im doing a motion analysis?

Comment: No, but some research by you might find them.

Comment: @Tony - if you're specifically worried about motion analysis, then use mate controllers? https://www.ccsl-cad.co.uk/blog/solidworks/mate-controller/